# Help finishing this exercise!

Tags: improper-integrals

Given the following functions:

$$ F(t)= \int_0^\infty e^{-tx}\dfrac{\sin{x}}{x}\,dx, \quad t>0$$
$$ F_s(t)= \int_0^s e^{-tx}\dfrac{\sin{x}}{x}\,dx, \quad t \geq 0, s>0$$

1. Show that $F$ is well-defined in $(0,+\infty)$ and it is differentiable in that same interval. Compute $F'$ and $\lim_{t \to \infty} F(t)$. Finally, compute $F(t)$ and $\lim_{t \to 0^+} F(t)$
2. Compute $F_s'$ in $(0, +\infty)$. Show that $F_s$ is a equicontinous family of functions
3. Show that $\lim_{s \to \infty}F_s(t) = F(t)$ uniformly for $t \in (0,+\infty)$
4. Show that $\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin{x}}{x}\,dx = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$

I have already asked you about (3) ([Show that $\lim_{s \to \infty}F_s(t) = F(t)$ uniformly for $t \in (0,+\infty)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863044/show-that-lim-s-to-inftyf-st-ft-uniformly-for-t-in-0-infty)). Now I have 1,2 and 3 solved, but I don't quite know how to finish up things in (4)

Using the definition I have

$$ \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin{x}}{x}\,dx := \lim_{L \to \infty} \int_0^L \dfrac{\sin{x}}{x}\,dx$$

and I am guessing I should connect this somehow with $\lim_{t \to 0^+} F(t)$ (which I have already computed). Also, I have noticed that I have not used that $\{ F_s \}$ is equicontinous, maybe that is necessary?. Could you give me any hints about how to complete this?

Comment: Have you looked at [Arzelà-Ascoli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzela-Ascoli_theorem)?

Comment: @Trollkemada : Did you ever figure this out? I have the same question.

Answer (score -3):

**Given as a solution from [this post:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/solving-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-dx-frac-pi2)**

This can also be solved using double integrals.

Using the double integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \Bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xy} \sin x \,dy \Bigg)\, dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \Bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xy} \sin x \,dx \Bigg)\,dy$$
Notice that
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xy} \sin x\,dy = \frac{\sin x}{x}$$

We can then substitute this in and say:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{\sin x}{x} \Big) \,dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \Bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xy} \sin x \,dx \Bigg)\,dy$$
Now the right hand side can be found easily, using integration by parts.

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int e^{-xy} \sin x \,dx = -e^{-xy}{\cos x} - y \int e^{-xy} \cos x \, dx\\
&= -e^{-xy}{\cos x} - y \Big(e^{-xy}\sin x + y \int e^{-xy} \sin x \,dx \Big)\\
&= \frac{-ye^{-xy}\sin x - e^{-xy}\cos x}{1+y^2}.
\end{align*}$$
Thus $$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xy} \sin x \,dx = \frac{1}{1+y^2}$$
Thus $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{\sin x}{x} \Big) \,dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+y^2}\,dy = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: Thanks, but I am interested not in the integral itself, but in how to use the previous steps I have completed to conclude the result.

Comment: @Trollkemada the reason why I posted this solution was because your integral cannot be solved. Put it into any mathematical calculator such as Wolfram-Alpha, they will not give you a closed solution. This is one of the methods that was posted as an answer.

Comment: I know, but as I told you, I am not interested in any method for solving that integral. I am interested only in the method I proposed in the question.

Comment: You cannot solve your integral. Your solution cannot be done. Simple as that.

Comment: I find it strange that immediately after posting a solution for the integral, you claim it cannot be solved.

Comment: @Arkamis I meant that **his method** wasn't a suitable way to solve this integral

Comment: I believe that that is untrue by the Principle of Problem Existence.